# CFTree written in Swift

Tags: swift, core-foundation

I'm not getting far converting the following into Swift:

```swift
static CFTreeRef CreateMyTree(CFTypeRef rootObject) {
CFTreeContext ctx;
ctx.version = 0;
ctx.info = rootObject;
ctx.retain = CFRetain;
ctx.release = CFRelease;
ctx.copyDescription = CFCopyDescription;  
return CFTreeCreate(NULL, &ctx);
}
```

I'm trying to set up the context with the following code

```
let context = CFTreeContext(version: 1, info: nil, retain: CFRetain, release: CFRelease, copyDescription: CFCopyDescription)
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I create and use a CFTree in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var info = "info"
let ctx = CFTreeContext(version: 0, info: &info, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
let tree = CFTreeCreate(nil, [ctx])
let child1 = CFTreeCreate(nil, [ctx])
print(tree)
```

Comment: Does disabling retain/release work correctly inside of CFTree? If the object isn't retained elsewhere by ARC, I'd be very concerned that it would become a dangling pointer because CFTree wouldn't retain it.